# Bijections of finite linear spaces preserving non-triviality of dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime, $FD_p$ the finite field of order $p$, $n\ge 3$, $V=(F_p)^n$ and let $f:V \to V$ be a bijection such that the dot products $u \cdot v$ and $f(u) \cdot f(v)$ are either both zero or both non-zero for all $u,v \in V$. Is $f$ a linear function on $V$?

I am just using the standard dot product on $V$ relative to some fixed basis.

The result is true for small values of $n$ and $p$, as can be checked using, for example, Magma.

I am expecting that this is a standard result in finite projective geometry, but have yet to find a reference.

Let $PV=\{a_1,\cdots,a_k\}$ be the corresponding projective space where $k=|PV|$. Let $M$ be the $k \times k$ matrix over $\mathbb Q$ with the $i,j$ entry $0$ if and only if $a_i \cdot a_j =0$, otherwise it is $1\in \mathbb Q$.

Then $S_k \times S_k$ acts by permuting the rows and columns of $M$. Also $G=SL(n,p)$ acts on $V$ and $V^*$ giving a permutation  action on the rows and columns of $M$ (respectively). Thus there is a homomorphism $G \to S_k \times S_k$ that is injective. The dot product is just the action of $V^*$ on $V$ in this setup.

So the problem is equivalent to showing that the centralizer  in $S_k \times S_k$ of $M$ is the image of $G$ in $S_k \times S_k$.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE. We require that questions here not only to state the problem, but also provide some of your own efforts in solving the problem. Even if it's something that lead nowhere, it's useful information, and shows you are engaged with the problem. You might also want, for clarity's sake, to specify explicitly what the dot product means, and also elaborate on $F_p$. I assume it's a finite field of order $p$, but is $p$ prime here? Or can $p$ be a power of a prime? Details like this will help clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true, and here's a counterexample. Let $V = F_3^3$. Define $f(x, y, z)$ by
$$f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases} (-x, y, z) & \text{if } y = z = 0 \\(x, y, z) & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
This map stabilises (permutes, even) one-dimensional subspaces (lines through the origin). Orthogonality is a property not just of pairs of vectors, but pairs of one-dimensional subspaces, as the dot product is bilinear. As such, any pair of orthogonal one-dimensional subspaces will map to the same pair of orthogonal one-dimensional subspaces, and so orthogonality is preserved.

However, the function is certainly not linear. For example,
$$f(1, 0, 0) + f(0, 1, 0) = (2, 0, 0) + (0, 1, 0) \neq (1, 1, 0) = f(1, 1, 0).$$

Comment: A counterexample spoiling scalar homogeneity can be presented on request.

Comment: I was hoping for a map that was non-trivial for its action on the projective space PV. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: @StephenHumphries So, compose this with an orthogonality-preserving linear map (orthogonal/unitary map?), such as $(x, y, z) \mapsto (y, z, x)$. That will non-trivially permute the projective space, but still maintain orthogonality.